# How to read a file into list with integers instead of strings?

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a file and return an output with an integer list of lists.

File `knapsack1.txt`:

```
1,2,4,6,9,10
3,4,7,11,12,16
15
```

Code:

```py
def greedy_thief(file_name, heuristic):

    f= open(file_name)
    mylist = []
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        mylist.append([items[0]] + [int(item) for item in items[1:]])

    return mylist

print(greedy_thief("knapsack1.txt",test_expensive))
```

The expected result is supposed to be `[[1,2,4,6,9,10], [3,4,7,11,12,16], [15]]`,
but I get `[['1,2,4,6,9,10'], ['3,4,7,11,12,16'], ['15']]`.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: In addition to @MrGeek's answer, I notice that you open a file in your `greedy_thief()` function, but don't close that file. You may want to replace `f= open(file_name)` with the expression `with open(file_name) as f:`, and then make the changes to indentation that go with that.

Comment: @jjramsey okay!! ill include that. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `line` has no spaces in it, `line.split()` will return a list that has only one element, which is line itself, that's why `[items[0]]` has a string (`line`) and since `items` has one element only, `items[1:]` is empty, so the second list comprehension is resulting in an empty list, you should split by the comma to get the numbers separated:

```
for line in f:
    items = line.split(',')
    mylist.append([int(item) for item in items])
```

You can also use map for this:

```
for line in f:
    mylist.append(list(map(int, line.split(','))))
```